# Detect Factory Reset on iPhone from within app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the need to check when an iPhone has been factory reset. There aren't any (that I've seen) Api calls to check when the iPhone got reset. So is there any file or something on the iPhone that gets deleted or modified when reseting an iPhone?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How could your app detect a factory reset? When the factory reset occurs, your app would be deleted along with all the other apps and data on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to get notified or find out about an eventual factory reset. There are two main reasons for this:

- Apple doesn't want you to know. Apps have very strict rules, they are separate apps and are not to interfere with the internal affairs of the phone itself.
- If an eventual factory reset has occured, the app, along with any other data, will be deleted. That means you can only figure out if the app has been deleted and reinstalled by comparing UDID's, which you are not allowed to by Apple.

Comment: You also will not be able to detect the UUID device, you will have to generate one and save it and on new install you will have a new one. Look to the ios 5 and see that the device UUID is depreciated and sooner or later will be removed from the public api.

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect any thing with public apis. So maybe there are private ones to detect factory reset date or some thing like that. But since they are private I think that you have to write a mail to apple or to a guy that works there.